# How to set up completion handlers in API Call - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've run into a problem.
I've made a service for API calls that returns a `User` object, and the API call works fine and it returns the `User` object.

However, I need to use completion and @escaping, and I'm not sure how to do it properly, since I'm new to Swift and iOS development.

The Code is below.

```
func login(with credentials: LoginCredentials) {
    let params = credentials
    AF.request(Service.baseURL.appending("/user/login"), method: .post, parameters: params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Success")
        case.failure:
            print("Fail")
        }
    }
```

Also, how do I call a function when there is completion?

Comment: You don't see it, but you are currently using one. `responseJSON(someOptionalParameters, completionHandler: @escaping (AFDataResponse<Any>) -> Void)`. It's the same logic here.

Comment: not quite clear: do you want to pass a completion handler to `login` function, and call it instead of `print("Success")`? And what kind of data that completion handler should receive?

Comment: @KirilS. Yeah, thats exactly what I want to do. Completion should receive `<Result User, Error>`

Comment: The provided answer is giving you a good starting point I think. The queue is not really needed there, and generally it's best if caller manages the queue, and not the generic function. You also need to change the arguments (replace `(Bool)` with `(User, Error)`). But otherwise it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear what kind of argument (if it takes one) the completion for your method shall take, thus I’m gonna give you a couple of hints.
Perhaps you want to also have the completion for your method execute on a queue specified as parameter in the call.
Therefore you might structure your method’s signature in this way:

```
func login(with credentials: LoginCredentials, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, _ completion: @esacping (Bool) -> Void)
```

Here I’ve used the type `Bool` as argument for the completion to be executed, and defaulted the queue argument to be `.main`, assuming that you’re just interested in deliver as result argument in the completion a value of `true` in case you’ve gotten a `.success` response, `false` otherwise; I’m also assuming that this method will mainly be called with the completion being executed on the main thread for updating a state, hence the default value for the `queue` argument.

Therefore your method body could become like this:

```
func login(with credentials: LoginCredentials, queue: DispatchQueue = .main, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let params = credentials
    AF.request(
        Service.baseURL.appending("/user/login"), 
        method: .post, 
        parameters: params, 
        encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default
    ).responseJSON { response in
          switch response.result {
          case .success:
              queue.async { completion(true) }
          case.failure:
              queue.async { completion(false) }
          }
}
```

Now of course if you need to deliver something different (as in the token for the login session and an error in case of failure) then you’d better adopt a `Result<T,Error>` Swift enum as argument to pass to the completion.
Without you giving more details in these regards, I can only give a generic suggestion for this matter, cause I cannot go into the specifics.

**EDIT**

As a bonus I'm also adding how you could structure this method with the new Swift concurrency model:

```
// Assuming you are returning either a value of type User or 
// throwing an error in case the login failed (as per your comments):
func login(with credentials: LoginCredentials) async throws -> User {
    withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in 
        AF.request(
            Service.baseURL.appending("/user/login"), 
            method: .post, 
            parameters: credentials, 
            encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default
        ).responseJSON { response in
              switch response.result {
              case .success:
                  let loggedUser = User(/* your logic to create the user to return*/)
              continuation.resume(returning: loggedUser)
              case.failure:
                  continuation.resume(throwing: User.Error.loginError)
              }
    }
}

// Here's possible way to implement the error on your User type
extension User {
    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case loginError
        // add more cases for other errors related to this type
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah I will use 'Result <User, Error>' to pass on completion.

However, on success I will redirect user to another View and on fail I will show alert. And I'm calling the function from 'LoginViewController'.

Comment: Generally you don't need a DispatchQueue in this solution - it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: @KirilS. well you don't know on which queue `responseJSON` will execute its completion handler (most likely on a private queue), thus it would be good idea to implement the method that relies on it in the way I've pointed out.

Comment: @valeCocoa No, passing queues as function argument is a definite sign of bad architecture (especially defaulting to `.main` queue). If your call back needs to run on a specific queue, the callback itself is responsible for making that happen once it's called (which is not hard). Most importantly though this design choice has nothing to do with question in hand

Comment: @KirilS. While I could agree with you if we were talking about a general API, in this case it suits his needs cause obviously that method will only be used in his own application, hence this is a convenience for his purpose. BTW this whole method should also be implemented nowadays with the new swift structured concurrency design, hence marking the function as `async throws` and adopting a throwing continuation in its body for interfacing with the closure based API.